# Prove context-free or not context-free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Given the following language:

$L=\{a^{p^2}|$ $p$ is prime$\}$

How can I show that this language is not context free using the pumping lemma?
I'm having trouble breaking it up to $s = uvxyz$.

would love to get some help.

thanks

Comment: Any suggestions? :[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
P_2 \equiv \{p^2 : p \text{ is prime}\}.
$$
Thus, $L\equiv \{a^r: r\in P_2\}$.
Suppose $L$ is context free. Then by the pumping lemma, there is an integer $q$ such that for all $s\in L$ with $|s|\ge q$, there exist $u,v,x,y,z$ with

- $s=uvxyz$,
- $|vxy|\le q$,
- $|vy|\ge 1$, and
- $uv^nxy^nz\in L$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Take such an $s,u,v,w,x,y,z$. Obviously, we can write $u=a^{r_u}$, $v=a^{r_v}$, $x=a^{r_x}$, $y=a^{r_y}$, and $z=a^{r_z}$ for some constants $r_u,r_v,\ldots$. Since $|vy|\ge 1$, it follows $r_v+r_y>0$. And since $uv^nxy^nz\in L$ for all $n\ge 0$, it follows that for all $n\ge 0$,
$$
r_u + r_x + r_z + n(r_v + r_y) \in P_2.
$$
This later statement cannot be true. To see this, let $p,p'$ be two consecutive primes. Then $\delta\equiv p'-p\ge 2$, so $p'^2 - p^2 = (p+\delta)^2 - p^2 = 2p\delta + \delta^2\ge 4p+4$. Thus, the gap between the squares of consecutive primes grows without bound, so there can be *no* infinitely long arithmetic progression among $P_2$.

By contradiction, $L$ is not context free.

Comment: . Thus, the gap between the squares of consecutive primes grows without bound, so there can be no infinitely long arithmetic progression among P2. => can you explain again?

Comment: Look at the statement, "For all $n\ge 0$, $r_u+r_x+r_z+n(r_v+r_y)\in P_2$". If that's true, there's an infinitely long arithmetic progression in $P_2$. Just look at values of that expression for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$. It's an arithmetic progression, right? And it's infinitely long, because it's true for all $n\ge 0$.

Comment: @Rouki Did you understand the proof?

Comment: Partly. I fully understood the infinitely long arithmetic progression in P2 but I still don't understand how , by showing that the gap between squares grow without bound , the language is not context free. just a clarification about that please :)

Comment: NVM. Fully understood now. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Parikh's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem) which implies that any context-free language of $a^*$ is regular. Then it suffices to use the pumping lemma for regular languages to show that $L$ is not regular. I let you do this part, which is pretty easy.